# Compare a string database value with more than two words

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

I have a table of users on my database containing the field "Full Name"

On my tool, I am uploading some files and before inserting the data on the database I am checking whether the user exists for example or not by comparing the full name field on the database with the one on the file (It is the only option, I cannot compare the ids).

My question is : How it is possible to compare those fields when they contains more than two words ?

Sometime the full names are not in order, for example :

```
-------------------------------------------------
|        Database       ||         File         |
-------------------------------------------------
| Michael Yves Pierrot  || Pierrot Michael Yves |
| Martin Dupont         || Dupont Martin        |
| Ben Jack Dupont       || Ben Dupont Jack      |
-------------------------------------------------
```

When there is only two words, it's Ok I work with splits like that :

```
public string getId()
{
    string result;
    QueryModel Query = new QueryModel();
    string sql = "SELECT Username_Id FROM USERNAME WHERE Full_name = '" 
        + Full_name.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
    result = Query.ExecuteCommand(sql, "int");
    if (result != "0")
    {
        string FullName2 = Full_name.Split(' ')[1] + " " + Full_name.Split(' ')[0];
        sql = "SELECT Username_Id FROM USERNAME WHERE Full_name = '" 
            + FullName2.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
        result = Query.ExecuteCommand(sql, "int");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note `Query.ExecuteCommand(sql, "int");` returns `"0"` when the user does not exists.

So if my function `getId()` returns `"0"` I will insert the new user, if it returns something else, that means the user exists and will return the `Username_Id`

Anyone have an Idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: perhaps use the '%' operator?

Comment: One indicator if they are the same can be length of string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something bad like the below (bad because of potential performance costs):

```
SELECT Username_Id 
FROM USERNAME 
WHERE Full_name LIKE '%Michael%' AND Full_name LIKE '%Pierrot%'
```

The '%' operator is for wildcards. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189454.aspx

I'd parameterize your query as well to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks. As far as the injections are concerned, I am developing an internal tool, I don't have to worry about that !

Comment: @aBennouna Parameterised queries have more advantages than just preventing SQL Injection. They also allow for query plan caching, so your query does not have to be compiled every time it is executed. It is also much more strongly typed, and avoids accidental truncation because you can specify length. So even if your system is not vulnerable to hacks, you should use parameterised queries for accuracy and performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @user1666620 I have modified my function, and the new code is:

```
public string getId()
{
    string result;
    QueryModel Query = new QueryModel();
    string[] fullName = Full_name.Replace("'", "''").Split(' ');
    string fullNameSQL = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < fullName.Count() - 1; i++)
    {
        string fn = "Full_Name LIKE '%" + fullName[i] + "%' ";
        fullNameSQL = (fullNameSQL == "") ? fn : fullNameSQL + " AND " + fn;
    }
    string sql = "SELECT Username_Id FROM USERNAME WHERE " + fullNameSQL;
    result = Query.ExecuteCommand(sql, "int");
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return all parts split and re-concatenated in alphabetical order. You could make a function out of it and use it directly within your compare

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(FullName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Michael Yves Pierrot'),('Michael Pierrot Yves'),('Martin Dupon'),('Dupont Martin'),('Ben Jack Dupont'),('Ben Dupont Jack');

WITH
NamesSplitByXML AS
(
    SELECT FullName
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY FullName) AS inx
          ,CAST('<root><r>' + REPLACE(tbl.FullName,' ','</r><r>') + '</r></root>' AS XML) AS NameAsXml
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
)
,SortedList AS
(
    SELECT inx, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY inx,x.y.value('.','varchar(max)')) AS inx2, FullName,x.y.value('.','varchar(max)') AS NamePart
    FROM NamesSplitByXML
    CROSS APPLY NameAsXml.nodes('/root/r') AS x(y)
) 
,DistinctInx AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT inx,FullName FROM SortedList
)
SELECT DistinctInx.inx,FullName,ConcatAlphabetical.SortedName
FROM DistinctInx
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STUFF(
    (
        SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT ' ' + NamePart
        FROM SortedList WHERE DistinctInx.inx=SortedList.inx
        ORDER BY inx2
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
    ).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,'')
) AS ConcatAlphabetical(SortedName)
```

Comment: @aBennouna, Sorry for asking as there is an accepted answer already, but I spent quite some time on this (I love tricky SQL hacks!) and I'm just curious, if you had a look on this. Would it work for you?

Comment: Sorry @Shnugo I've just seen your answer, I've tested it and it works ! Thanks ;-)

Comment: @aBennouna, thx, glad to hear this... One advantage of my approach is, that - if you fill in smaller parts, the LIKE-search could easily return wrong results, other names could contain these parts too. If you stick with the LIKE way, you should think about adding spaces: LIKE "% pierre %". This making sure not find parts of names...

Comment: I need help in Triggers as I know you love SQL. Is it possible to give me a hand ? @Shnugo

Comment: @aBennouna, yes of course! Please place a new question here on SO, tag it with "sql-server" and "trigger" and what else fits to your needs and you can be shure, that a helping armade will fall in just like wesps on a plum cake. Please use the "share" button below your question to get a link. If you post this here (with `@Shnugo`) I'll get an alert and will pop up there soon :-)